# Validate and allow specific username to login in username text field of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ajaxform

I want to allow only two selected users to login to my application **on-click of submit button**. These two usernames are listed in a text file called as **user.txt** so, the username parameter should be read and if the username entered in the text field matches the entries of the user.txt file then the user must be allowed to login else error should be displayed.

**Note:** The challenge here I already have one validation(**validateForm())** which is working fine on click of the submit button. It checks to ensure the username and password fields are not empty. I need this **new specific username allow validation** validation as well on-click of  submit button.

Can someone suggest me example codes how can I handle this validation using Ajax or jQuery or simple JavaScript?

**Username.txt file**

```
Username1 : Tom
Username2 : Harry
```

**Check whether username and password text fields are not empty:**

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["login"]["userid"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Username is empty");
        return false;
    }
    var x = document.forms["login"]["pswrd"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Password is empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Authentication shouldn't be done in JavaScript. This is because JS runs in the browser, and the user has complete control over the browser. That means they can bypass any user restrictions that are only enforced by JS. What server side stack are you using?

Comment: You should be handling your validation server-side, at least. Client-side validation is just eye candy, as it's easily "hacked".
You don't want to have these usernames visible to the client.

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you but you could easily send an AJAX call in the ValidaeForm function that would call a Web service that could read the text file and compare to the value entered, provide a response to the page and then react accordingly to the user.

Comment: currently i want to do it in client side validation and the validation input file is a .txt file in which valid user names are provided. I need to read these username each and every time a user enters his/her name in the username text field and if the name matches the user should be allowed to enter into the application. The username.txt file is present in the location C:\\username.txt

Comment: @Dojo_user: I'd suggest you to look up some authentication tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at tutorials [**like this one**](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/ajax-login-validation-php-jquery.html) if you want proper (secure) authentication.

If you only want to check against the usernames, try this jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script_url",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        user : $("#user").val(),
        call : "checkUser"  
    },
    beforeSend: function(){ },
    success : function(response){
        if(!response){
            alert('User not allowed!');
        }
    },
    complete: function(){ }
})
```

And PHP code:

```
$lines = file('../location/Username.txt');
$arr_users = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
    $arr = explode(':', $line);
    $arr_users[] = trim($arr[1]);
}

function checkUser($request){
    return in_array($request['user']);
}

if (!empty($_POST['call'])) { 
    die($_POST['call']($_POST));
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: -1: This is nowhere near how authentication should be handled.
The server has no idea of what user is logged in, and as such, it's very easy to just break the client-side AJAX call, and get in.

Comment: Because the question may be about the wrong problem. The answer the OP **wants** can still be a **very, very bad idea.** This answer doesn't even mention the fact that this just fakes what authentication looks like, to the user.

Comment: sure it is but he will figure that out, otherwise I answered his question. So i don't understand your GURU atitude.

Comment: If the OP could figure that out, he/she wouldn't have asked this question. My "GURU attitude" is me trying to explain to the OP that there's more to secure authentication than this, or than there is in the question. I'm trying to make the OP learn something. At very least add a big fat warning to your answer telling people that read this that it's a bad idea to do it this way.

Comment: Dojo_user you should also check Cerbrus answers regarding Ajax authentification he is more advised then me. Cerbrus thank you!

Comment: also Cerbrus you should reconsider your downvote since I recognized my wickeness...

Comment: I'm glad you understand my point of view, but that doesn't change the fact that the answer isn't very good, I'm sorry...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check against the server, where the file.txt is located (btw: databases are used for that purpose, usually).

The only way to do it on client side (javascript), is to have the list of names inside an array - but that doesn't make sense - as the client would be able to see the array.
So you really should use server side for that purpose.

Comment: Hi IT goldman, I have my username.txt file in my local machine C:\\username.txt from which I want to read the usernames and if it is valid one it should allow the specific user to enter into the application else it should show an invalid user message.This is a validation which I want to do for my text field in html

Comment: @Dojo_user: you can't access local machine files using javascript, by default.

Comment: we can using ajax or jquery. Place the files in the webapps folder of tomcat and you can access it